# Recommended way to search non-key attributes in DynamoDB

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a table of users, which have a primary key of UserId. This is great for requests on all users, or certain users, but in my case I want to get all users who have a lastActivity attribute (which is a number) that is greater than a certain value, in descending order.

As I look into the docs, it appears that you can only do queries based on primary indexes, but you can provide a `FilterExpression` property that will filter results from a scan and return them, but this doesn't list them in ascending order.

Is there something I am missing, or is using `FilterExpressions` the way that I am going to have to do this? If my app, let's say, has 10000 users, but only 50 of them are active at a given time, won't that make my query extremely inefficient?

Answer (score 2):

1. First option, as Mark recommended, if you use a sort key on lastActivity (LSI or otherwise), you will either:

   a. Have your records in one partition, so you can use the Query API.

   b. Have your records across multiple partition keys, you will still need to use the Scan API.
2. Another option is to use a GSI. If you set your partition key as lastActivity, the record will only appear in the GSI if the lastActivity attribute is present.
3. A third option is to use Streams + Lambda to replicate users to another table which has more appropriate Key Schema for your query, and potentially use TTL to clean up users, keeping in mind, the TTL removal is best effort (typically within 48 hours)

HTH

Abhaya

Answer (score 1):

You could add a sort key of `lastActivity` on your primary key.

Comment: Unfortunately, this ended up not working because you can't update attributes that are used as sort keys. LastActivity needs to be mutable so that the app can keep track of users last activity time.